# persisting multi-factor user data for custom pam authentication in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ssh, authentication, pam

I am designing n-factor authentication for CentOS 7 using a custom PAM module.  When the user tries to SSH, they will be texted a pin code, and be prompted to enter the pin.  **Where should I store the user's cell phone number?  And how should it be retrieved by the PAM module?**

I am starting by customizing [the 2ndfactor.c file shown in this link](http://ben.akrin.com/?p=1068).  The sample in the link uses a link to a web service, but my module will call a java program to send the text.  Sending is a separate question.  In this question, I want to know where to store the data and how to retrieve it in CentOS 7.  Is it stored in the OS?  In a database?  I don't want to create a security risk by leaving emails and phone numbers exposed somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should I store the user's cell phone number? And how should it be retrieved by the PAM module?

This is entirely your design decision.

Some PAM modules store information in local files in `/etc`, like `pam_access` or the [google authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator) module.

Other modules may contact a remote server, like the [radius authentication module](http://freeradius.org/pam_radius_auth/).

A scalable solution would probably involve some sort of database or directory service (like LDAP), so that the same information could be used on multiple servers.  A simple solution would probably store the information in local files, and making synchronizing these files across multiple servers a problem for the local administrator.